# Run Powershell as admin shows unknown publishser

Tags: powershell

I've been running PowerShell as admin for a while on this Windows Server 2008 R2 server. Today I noticed that the security dialog shows that the publisher for it is Unknown. I'm fairly certain Microsoft publishes PowerShell. I'm also fairly certain that's what used to be displayed, so now I'm concerned that my PowerShell installation is corrupt.

There doesn't seem to be a simple way to re-install or repair PowerShell on Windows Server 2008 R2. I installed WMF 4.0 but the problem persists.

How do I make sure I run the trusted PowerShell.exe?

Comment: 1. Are you sure you are running `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` or is the binary in another location?  2. Submit the binary to virustotal.com...

Comment: @RyanRies location is good, virustotal reports no problem.

Comment: @GuillaumeCR Try running  `sfc /verifyonly` from an elevated prompt to check for issues with your system files. If any are detected you can attempt to repair them with `sfc /scannow`. (A reboot may be required for the latter.)

Comment: @Viertaxa Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

Comment: Delete your shortcut and recreate a new one.  If that fails, go to the actual powershell.exe file in %windowsdir% and manually spy it's file specifications.  If the details are wrong there, please advise.

Comment: Eww, sketchy.  Do you have any custom, unsigned modules that PowerShell is trying to load, perhaps?

Comment: @Colyn1337 I get the same result when running the executable itself. The file details seem correct but like I answered Peter below, using sigcheck shows the publisher is n/a.

Comment: @HopelessN00b I do have my own module that should load up, but I don't see how that affects the powershell executable.

Comment: Well, try removing or disabling that module, then running PowerShell.  If that eliminates the unknown publisher warning, you have your answer.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Removed all module loading from profile. No change.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following:

```
sigcheck.exe -i C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

[sigcheck.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441.aspx) is a SysInternals tool you have to download

It should show you the certificates used to digitally sign the PowerShell executable.

I think not all the certificates have to be valid, but at least one.

Comment: Verified:       Unsigned
       Link date:      3:01 PM 8/26/2015
       Publisher:      n/a
       Company:        Microsoft Corporation
       Description:    Windows PowerShell
       Product:        Microsoft« Windows« Operating System
       Prod version:   10.0.10514.6
       File version:   10.0.10514.6 (th2_release_svc.150826-1230)
       MachineType:    64-bit

Comment: Ran with both the 32 and 64 bit version. Same results.

Comment: `Verified:  Unsigned` doesn't sound right, it should say `Verified: Signed`, the rest looks okay, but are all certificates valid?

Comment: Sigcheck did not display any certs, I assume because it detected the exe was not signed.

Comment: I would compare a file hash for PowerShell.exe with another machine and the same version and upload it to VirusTotal. I wouldn't trust it at this point

Comment: Yeah I'm not trusting it either. Where can I get the trusted version?

Comment: You already installed WMF 4.0, try WMF 5.0 if you still have an unsigned version, you should question the integrity of the whole OS.